Coverage Path Planning Dilemma (Trade-Off)
I have encountered a dilemma while I was trying to model a certain problem. Here is the description of the problem:
Imagine a 2D square area divided into square grids/cells. We have an agent (robot) that needs to sweep the entire area - the robot can move in 4 directions: up, down, right, and left. Assume that robot can move directly from/to the centers of each cell. Without loss of generality, assume that an agent starts its path from the lower-left corner (green cell in the picture below). The objective is to sweep the whole area with a certain contraint/caveat. Here is caveat: each cell has a priority, i.e., higher prioirty cells need to be reached as soon as possible. Let's assume priority runs from 1 to 4; 4 being the highest priority.
Here is the dilemma I am having:  The objective is to sweep the area as soon as possible, i.e., find a path such that minimizes the total sweeping area while prioritizing the cells with higher priority - visiting higher priority cells the sooner the better.
I have an intuition that there is a trade-off going on. If the agent sweeps the area in a linear fashion (lawn-mower fashion), there is a chance that higher priority cells will be visited later than sooner, but there will be no re-visits of cells. On the contrary, if the drone will follow the high-priority cells first, while high-priority cells will be reached out sooner there is a chance that there will be some re-visit of some cells (different than TSP) - potentially leading to increased distance/time traveled. What should be the balance?
I am interested in finding/exploring the balance between these two seemingly contradicting criteria. For that, I want to introduce a sense of "time/urgency" - visiting priority 4 cell at time step 3 should have a different value than visiting it at time step 7 for example.
For example, assume we have a 5 by 5 grid, with randomly assigned proirity to each cell - say priority matrix is {{2,4,1,2,1}, {1,3,4,4,2}, {1,3,2,3,1}, {1,1,2,2,1}, {2,2,3,4,2}}, like in the picture:

Color coding:
Green: Where the agent starts its path

Red: Highest priority cells (4 is the highest priority). 

What methodologies do you think will work here? What literature should I familirize myself with?
In the literature, there is an avenue known as (Complete) Coverage Path Planning - every cell should be visited. But this algorithms do not incorporate priorities. How could I model this problem as MIP? How could I formulate decision variables, the objective function, and the constraints. Especially the sequentiality of decisions in each time step perplexes me. Have you encountered a similar problem?

These are excellent insights to start with the modeling of the problem and solving them. There are a few ways to define your decision variables - I guess, and hence construct the objective function and add relevant constraints. I was wondering to which literature I could consult to to have even a deeper understanding of modeling of movements (or some well-known similar problem, e.g., first examples that comes to my mind are TSP and/or network flow problems), with alternative approaches and comparisons - which will potentially give me flexibility in terms of solutions approaches. I wonder how did you go about defining your decision variables and got empirical results for my provided small input data? Prior to posting, I did some scratch paper work by hand and the results are somehow consistent and makes sense - very close to what I have found.
In relation to defining one's decision variables, they should align with objective function and constraints - I believe - more importantly with the underlying problem. Your have suggested multiple approaches, which are good starting point I guess. Although, I have some questions related to that, for examples one of the questions is "could the objective function be counting/adding some nodes multiple times, i.e., when re-visiting, because 'nodes' could potentially appear both in the first and the second expression in the objective function? There is a need to capture/record the 'first visit time' of each node I guess - to avoid over-counting".
And constructing the Pareto frontiers is an excellent suggestion, because is provides a comprehensive solution whereby the user of the model can adjust any parameters to their need.

You can find a write-up of my IP formulation at https://rubin.msu.domains/blog/robot.pdf.

It is not difficult to model the movement portion of the problem using an integer linear program. (Finding the most efficient formulation, in solution time, might be a bit more challenging.) The fundamental issue you must face is how to handle the two objectives (minimizing movement and minimize prioritized waits). Movement is straightforward to measure. Prioritized waits is trickier.
Assume each move by the robot consumes one unit of time. Presumably you would want to incorporate integer variables for each node reflecting the time at which the robot first visits each cell. The most obvious way to formulate the second objective is to multiply the time of first visit by the priority of the cell and minimize the sum. That might not sufficiently capture urgency, though. So do you multiply by the square / cube / exponential of the priority? This is a question you would need to deal with in consultation with the source of the problem.
Once you have a formulation for the urgency function, the next question is how to balance urgency with travel time/distance. There are a number of ways of dealing with multiple objectives, including taking a weighted sum of the two, minimizing one subject to a prescribed limit on the other, or using "lexicographic order" (minimizing the primary objective, breaking ties based on the secondary objective).
Addendum: One other way to deal with the objectives (albeit with a considerable increase in computational burden) is to explore the Pareto frontier, obtaining a few "efficient solutions. You can then present them to the "owner" of the problem and let them decide what tradeoff between efficiency and urgency appeals to them.

FYI, I ran your example through two models with lexicographic objectives. "Distance" is the number of moves for the robot; "urgency" is the sum across all squares of the time at which the square is first visited multiplied by its priority. Both objectives are to be minimized. Prioritizing distance over urgency, the solution has distance 26 and urgency 561. Prioritizing urgency over distance, the solution has distance 28 and urgency 547.

Hello Dr.Rubin, instead of commenting, I have posted an answer below.
